# Probability that all the $n$ letters are not placed in the right envelope

Tags: probability, solution-verification, derangements

> There are $n$ letters and $n$ addressed envelopes. If the letters are placed in the envelopes at random, what is the probability that all the letters are not placed in the right envelope?

The number of ways in which no letter goes to the desired envelope is given by the $n$-th derangement number $D_n$. So the required probability is $\frac{D_n}{n!}$.

[However, all the sources say that the answer is $1-\frac{1}{n!}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=there+are+n+letters+and+n+addressed+envelopes&oq=there+are+n+letter&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57.5400j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

I believe that the answer given by all these websites is incorrect since they assumed the complement to be the number of ways in which **all** letters go to the desired envelopes instead of the number of ways in which **at least one** letter goes to the correct envelope.

I would like someone to verify this since im outnumbered.

Comment: What those sources are answering is probability that _some_ letters do not go into correct envelopes. That could be $2$ letters or more that do not go into correct envelopes.

Comment: when they say all letters do not go to correct envelopes, they mean some of them could still go into correct envelopes

Comment: @MathLover thats also a possibility. this is so confusing...

Comment: yes of course, it is, the nuances of a language and how it can be interpreted differently.

Comment: A full derangement statement would be *none* of the letters go in the right envelope. *All* letters don't go in the right envelope means an imperfect placement of  letters and envelopes.

Comment: @trueblueanil I agree, that might have been what they really meant in the question

Comment: A less ambiguous wording for the $1-1/n!$ question would be "not all of the letters are placed in the right envelope."